# Char array outputting correctly but not actually storing right values

Tags: c++, arrays, char

New to C++ and ran into another hurdle to learn from. Trying to make a simple program that reads from a file and stores the characters into a char array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int main () 
{
  const int SIZE = 9;
  char arr[SIZE];
  char currentChar;
  int numChar = 0;
  int i = 0;

  ifstream infile ("file.txt");

  if (!infile)
  {
      cout << "Can not open the input file"
           << " This program will end."<< "\n";
      return 1;
    }

  while(infile.get(arr[i]))
      {
          i++;
          numChar ++;
      }

  for(i=0;i<numChar;i++)
  {
      cout << arr[i];
  }

  cout << "\n" << arr[1];

  return 0;
}
```

Contents of file.txt:

```
A
a
9

!
```

Problem is that:

```
  for(i=0;i<numChar;i++)
  {
      cout << arr[i];
  }
```

Has output that is identical from the file read, but when I manually checked the array elements. arr[1] is storing a white space and arr[3] ='a'. I found this out when I was trying to evaluate what type of char each element was with isalpha and isdigit statements. Why is it storing 2 elements of whitespace before getting to the next line and why does the output look correct though it actually isn't? Is there a much simpler and more efficient way to this than what I'm doing?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Because on windows each line ends with a `newline` and a `linefeed` character before moving on to the new line.

Comment: If you are on a different platform (say linux) it would only end in a `newline`, so don't get any ideas about skipping two spaces (unless you could care less about running on linux, in which case you can do what ever you want)

Comment: There are newline characters after each line.

Comment: I'm actually on ubuntu 15.10. I kind of understand, correct me if i'm wrong. Because i'm reading to end of file instead of to each endline its putting them into the array. Syntax wise how could I change the while statement that reads the array so that when arr[i] = "\n" or some such thing that it ignores that and moves on and stores the array correctly?

Comment: @mrbw I don't know if you can actually do this, but the simplest solution would be to make all of the characters in the file on the same line.

Comment: That did it which will work for now on what I'm trying to learn. I'll have to bookmark this page so I know to come back to it later when I go about figuring this out. For some reason I didn't think that "\n" would be interpreted as a character but now that I think about it this way it makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What you are reading is a new line character next to each character in your file. if you cast the characters to int when you display them you get something like:

```
65 //ascii code for 'A' at arr[0]
10 //ascii code for new line character(\n) at arr[1]
97 //ascii code for 'a' at arr[2]
10
..
```

Comment: New Line is a white space.